# Is a motion picture camera an observer?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, observers

Assume the setup with Shroedinger's cat, but add a motion picture camera that starts to record the state of the cat from the instant you close the apparatus until you open it.  Is each frame of the film taken an observation?  Is each frame in a superimposed state until I view it or is the camera itself an observer?

Answer (score 1):

No, the photon, that you implicitly assume to be in the box (otherwise, the camera would have little benefit) is the observer - independently of whether there is a camera there to record it or not.

Answer (score 1):

The cat is its own observer. It "knows" its own state at any time. Once the box is opened an external observer can see if it is dead or alive. If alive, then it was always in an alive state. If dead, a skilled pathologist can even state the time at which it died, so that it was alive up until that time and dead afterwards.